# Exiting from a VB.NET With block

Tags: vb.net, with-statement

In the following block of code, does VB.NET gracefully exit the With block if `Var1 = 2`?

```
With MyObject
    .Property1 = "test"
    If Var1 = 2 Then
        Return True
    End If
    .Property2 = "Test2"
End With

Return False
```

I remember this being an issue in VB6 and causing headaches with unpredicable behaviour - is the same true of VB.NET?

Comment: Wow, that's strange. I've never experienced that behavior, despite all the time I spend programming in VB.NET. I guess there's a good reason why I never use `With` statements...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN, this still isn't possible:

[*If you need to exit before all the statements have been executed, put a label on the End With statement and use the GoTo Statement to branch to it. (...) You cannot transfer control either from outside a With block to inside it, or from inside it to the outside. You can call a procedure from inside the block, but control returns to the following statement.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

Comment: @slugster, hehe.. not advocating, merely citing, with no personal opinion expressed :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to add another answer here, because I was mainly curious. Never used WITH much, and I can't recall ever exiting the block prematurely, but I just tested this under VB2010 and it appears to work just fine (ie as I would expect it to, in other words...

If Var1 =2, the function returns TRUE, and the value of MyObject.Property1 is "Test" but MyObject.Property2 has not be set.

It's possible that it worked this way in a test, but in a real app of significant size, with debugging turned off etc, etc, it could work differently, so, there's that to consider....

Comment: Yeah, the way I read this is that transferring control out of a `With` statement is not technically supported. That doesn't mean it won't work: the code is going to return no matter what because you threw a `return` statement in there. But that doesn't mean that everything gets cleaned up nicely and there's no potentially buggy behavior to be accounted for. This is one of those times in programming where you have to consider things beyond "does it compile?" when making a design decision.